# creating subclass form class returning pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, inheritance, pandas

In my project I build a class with pandas DataFrame as a core. The values in dataframe depends upon some specification and I initialise it with some letter representing the data I want to work with. I put all my functions to create dataframe inside an `__init__` as I understand this functions are one off only and no needs for them after the initialisation. Also I don't want to have access to this functions after my class is in use in later code. (I am not sure if this is "pythonic" way to do so).

After building basic class with `__str__` and plotData() methods I would like to apply some filters and build a new class where additional column is the filter. I would like to do that in `__init__` but keep everything what already was done. In another words I don't want to re-write the whole `__init__` only want to add new column to the basic dataframe.

In similar fashion I would like to add an additional plot in the plotData() function

My original code has already quite a few of lines but the principles are very similar to code listed below.

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, frameType = 'All'):
        def method1():
            myFrame = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,3],'c2':[4,5,6],'c3':[7,8,9]})
            return myFrame
        def method2():
            myFrame = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[.1,.2,.3],'c2':[.4,.5,.6],'c3':[.7,.8,.9]})
            return myFrame
        def makingChiose(self):
            if self.frameType == 'All':
                variable = method1() + method2() 
            elif self.frameType == 'a':
                variable = method1()
            elif self.frameType == 'b':
                variable = method2()
            else:
                variable =  pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,0,0],'c2':[0,0,0],'c3':[0,0,0]})
            #print 'FROM __init__ : %s' % variable
            return variable           
        self.frameType = frameType      
        self.cObject = makingChiose(self) # object created by the class
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cObject)
    def plotData(self):
        self.fig1 = pl.plot(self.cObject['c1'],self.cObject['c2'])
        self.fig2 = pl.plot(self.cObject['c1'],self.cObject['c3'])
        pl.show()

class myClassAv(myClass):
    def addingCol(self):
        print 'CURRENT cObject \n%s' % self.cObject # the object is visible 
        self.cObject['avarage'] = (self.cObject['c1']+self.cObject['c2']+self.cObject['c3'])/3
        print 'THIS WORKS IN GENERAL\n%s' % str((self.cObject['c1']+self.cObject['c2']+self.cObject['c3'])/3) # creating new column works
    def plotData(self):
        # Function to add new plot to already existing plots
        self.fig3 = pl.plot(self.cObject['c1'],self.cObject['avarage'])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myObject1 = myClass()
    print 'myObject1 =\n%s' % myObject1
    myObject1.plotData()
    myObject2 = myClass('a')
    print 'myObject2 =\n%s' % myObject2
    myObject3 = myClass('b')
    print 'myObject3 =\n%s' % myObject3
    myObject4 = myClass('c')
    print 'myObject4 =\n%s' % myObject4

    myObject5 = myClassAv('a').addingCol()
    print 'myObject5 =\n%s' % myObject5
    myObject5.plotData()
```

Most of the code works, at least in the initialisation but I have an error when I try to create new dataframe with additional column. When I put as the new `__init__` I create a completely new initialisation and I loose all what was already done. I created a new function but I would prefer have the additional column after I call a new class not a function inside the new class The output from the code looks like this:

```
myObject1 =
    c1   c2   c3
0  1.1  4.4  7.7
1  2.2  5.5  8.8
2  3.3  6.6  9.9
myObject2 =
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
myObject3 =
    c1   c2   c3
0  0.1  0.4  0.7
1  0.2  0.5  0.8
2  0.3  0.6  0.9
myObject4 =
   c1  c2  c3
0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
CURRENT cObject 
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
THIS WORKS IN GENERAL
0    4
1    5
2    6
myObject5 =
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\src\trys.py", line 57, in <module>
    myObject5.plotData()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'plotData'
```

The question is: Can I 'partially' override the superclass's method to have what was previously inside this method with some new functionality? I would like to initialise myClassAv() to dataframe with four columns instead of three like myClass() and I'd like to have myClassAv().plotData() to plot a third line but keep two from base class.

I don't know how to interpret an error and why myObject5 is None, but I suspect it is something with inheritance.

Also if you have suggestion that I should do all my idea in different way I will appreciate to hear them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about just call `myClass.__init__` inside `myClassAv.__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, frameType='All'):
    myClass.__init__(self, frameType)
    def addingCol(cObject): 
        ...
    addingCol(self.cObject)
```

---

For concreteness,

```
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np


class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self, frameType='All'):
        def method1():
            myFrame = pd.DataFrame(
                {'c1': [1, 2, 3], 'c2': [4, 5, 6], 'c3': [7, 8, 9]})
            return myFrame

        def method2():
            myFrame = pd.DataFrame(
                {'c1': [.1, .2, .3], 'c2': [.4, .5, .6], 'c3': [.7, .8, .9]})
            return myFrame

        def makingChoice(self):
            if self.frameType == 'All':
                variable = method1() + method2()
            elif self.frameType == 'a':
                variable = method1()
            elif self.frameType == 'b':
                variable = method2()
            else:
                variable = pd.DataFrame(
                    {'c1': [0, 0, 0], 'c2': [0, 0, 0], 'c3': [0, 0, 0]})
            # print 'FROM __init__ : %s' % variable
            return variable
        self.frameType = frameType
        self.cObject = makingChoice(self)  # object created by the class

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cObject)

    def plotData(self):
        self.fig1 = pl.plot(self.cObject['c1'], self.cObject['c2'])
        self.fig2 = pl.plot(self.cObject['c1'], self.cObject['c3'])
        pl.show()


class myClassAv(myClass):
    def __init__(self, frameType='All'):
        myClass.__init__(self, frameType)

        def addingCol(cObject):
            print 'CURRENT cObject \n%s' % cObject  # the object is visible
            cObject['average'] = cObject.mean(axis=1)
            # creating new column works
            print 'THIS WORKS IN GENERAL\n%s' % str(cObject['average'])
            return cObject

        addingCol(self.cObject)

    def plotData(self):
        # Function to add new plot to already existing plots
        self.fig3 = pl.plot(self.cObject['c1'], self.cObject['average'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myObject1 = myClass()
    print 'myObject1 =\n%s' % myObject1
    myObject1.plotData()
    myObject2 = myClass('a')
    print 'myObject2 =\n%s' % myObject2
    myObject3 = myClass('b')
    print 'myObject3 =\n%s' % myObject3
    myObject4 = myClass('c')
    print 'myObject4 =\n%s' % myObject4

    myObject5 = myClassAv('a')
    print 'myObject5 =\n%s' % myObject5
    myObject5.plotData()
```

---

By the way, instead of

```
self.cObject['avarage'] = (self.cObject['c1']+self.cObject['c2']+self.cObject['c3'])/3
```

you can use `mean(axis = 1)`:

```
self.cObject['average'] = self.cObject.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu, this is what I need. Would you add some comment if nesting methods inside methods is general and good practice?

Comment: First, I apologize for responding so late. I think I must close tabs too quickly or something since I don't always see a notification when people write to me. Regarding nesting of functions: if you believe a function has a general purpose or is reusable, then it should be defined at the top level of a module or some place where other functions can call it. If a function has a very specialized purpose (is not reusable) or if you want to keep the top level namespace tidy, then it is okay to nest the function. The Zen of Python say "Flat is better than nested" so if in doubt, don't nest.

Comment: Nesting can alse be used to *prevent* people from calling a function. However, it won't stop the determined hacker, so the benefit of nesting for this purpose is probably dubious.